# Error downloading file from my Node.js server

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to make a download link on my server for a zip file and I'm currently getting this error: (Note, still just testing it on local machine)

```
{ [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Users\Jordan\Desktop\Websites\HappyCamel\Users\Jordan\Desktop\Websites\HappyCamel']
errno: -4058,
code: 'ENOENT',
syscall: 'stat',
path: 'C:\\Users\\Jordan\\Desktop\\Websites\\HappyCamel\\Users\\Jordan\\Desktop\\Websites\\HappyCamel',
expose: false,
statusCode: 404,
status: 404 }
```

The relevant code is this:

```
router.get('/file/:name', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('test123'); //successfully prints to console
    res.download('Users/Jordan/Desktop/Websites/HappyCamel/', 'test123.zip', function(err) {
        console.log('test456'); //successfully prints to console
        if(err) { 
            console.log(err) //I'm assuming this is source of logged error
        } else {
            console.log("no error"); //doesn't print
        }
    });
})
```

edit:

Fixed it with changing this line:

```
res.download('Users/Jordan/Desktop/Websites/HappyCamel/', 'test123.zip', function(err) {
```

to

```
res.download('./test123.zip', 'test123.zip', function(err) {
```

but now I get

```
angular.min.js:114 ReferenceError: success is not defined
```

error on my browser, but no errors in my node console (my "no error" line is printing)

Comment: does that path exist? the structure looks odd because you have Users\Jordan .... \Users\Jordan repeated twice. your download path is more than likely going to want to have something like __dirname + 'path'

Answer (score 2):

you are using relative path. when you do this:

```
res.download('Users/Jordan/Desktop/Websites/HappyCamel/', 'test123.zip', function(err) {
```

it will look for `Users/Jordan/Desktop/Websites/HappyCamel/` inside your current file's directory. looks like what you need is full path, or better a correct relative path- from the error it looks like the file is located with your code, so this should do:

```
res.download('./', 'test123.zip', function(err) {
```

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it by changing it to  

    `res.download('./test123.zip', 'test123.zip', function(err) {`  

but now I get  

    `angular.min.js:114 ReferenceError: success is not defined`  

on my browser, no error from node. Any idea what it should be?